# SQL: Get parent Join child where child type = 1 AND child type = 2

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have question in SQL (MySQL environment). I have two tables:

```
Airports
--------------------
id    type   city_id
1     2      1
2     3      1
3     4      2


City
----------
id    name
1     Paris
2     Lyon
```

I want cities with airports whose type is 2 and 3.

I have try:

```
SELECT *
FROM city c INNER JOIN airports a ON a.city_id = c.id
WHERE a.type = 1 AND a.type = 2
```

But it does not work.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You mean a.type having both values 1 and 2? Like Paris?

Comment: @prcaen My query returns only the airports which have exactly 2 and 3 types only and fails if any other types are present including 2 and 3.I hope you were trying to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need cities where type 1 and 2 airports exist both then try to use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM CITY
JOIN
  (
     SELECT CITY_ID FROM Airports WHERE type in (1,2)
     GROUP BY CITY_ID
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) =2
   ) as A
  ON City.ID=a.City_id
```

Comment: Please note that there is assumption (type, city_id) is UNIQUE. If there is airports row like `(id, type, city_id) = (2, 2, 1)` this query returns invalid output.

Comment: @InoSHeo This is the reason of using `COUNT(DISTINCT type)`. So it will work right.

Comment: aha. Apology me. I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are after the record paris which has two different types(1 and 2), try this:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM city c INNER JOIN 
     airports a ON a.city_id = c.id
WHERE a.type IN (2,3)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.type)>1
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME
1   Paris
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57bf0/10).

**To be more detailed:**

```
SELECT c.id as CID,a.Id as AID,type,city_id,name
FROM city c INNER JOIN
     airports a ON a.city_id=c.id LEFT JOIN
(SELECT c.id
 FROM city c INNER JOIN 
      airports a ON a.city_id = c.id
 WHERE a.type IN (2,3)
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.type)>1) T ON T.id=c.id
WHERE T.id IS NOT NULL
```

Result:

```
CID  AID    TYPE    CITY_ID  NAME
1    1      2       1        Paris
1    2      3       1        Paris
```

Fiddle [**Example**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57bf0/15).

Comment: Your query is not correct it also works when the airport has some other type apart from 2 and 3 for example 4.Check this for more info http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccee33/1.I have added a new type 5 to airport id 1 but still it returns answer as paris instead of null set.

Comment: @user1613360: Thats why I used where clause. OP says he want to check with 2,3. It works perfectly with any other type. Please see [**this fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f437/1).

Comment: I think he wants only 2 and 3 nothing else.Anyways he should decide...:p

Comment: @user1613360: Yes ofcourse! OP is trying to get the cities having airport types 2 and 3. That is what my query gets. Please read the question.

Comment: @prcaen: It doesn't matter. If you want to search against any other types, just change the values in `IN clause`. And change the value against `count`.

Comment: @RagingBull: Your both sql queries returns me only one result. However several airports meet the criteria.

Comment: @prcaen: What you mean by several airports. Can you show an example? I have tested it with the given sample data and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query

```
 SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(a.type) as tp
   FROM city c INNER JOIN airports a ON a.city_id = c.id
   WHERE a.type IN (1,2)
) tmp WHERE tp = "1,2";
```

And here you replace 1,2 (in the sub-query also) with the values you require

```
 SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT c.id, c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(a.type) as tp
   FROM city c JOIN airports a ON a.city_id = c.id
   WHERE a.type IN (2,3)
) tmp WHERE tp = "2,3";
```

the above one returns correct data also

Comment: With the SQL `OR` clause give me cities which have type 1 or type 2. But I want the cities that have both types 1 and 2

Comment: I have added one more query, hopefully this meets your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
SELECT *
FROM city c jINNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT city_id
    FROM airports t1 INNER JOIN airports t2
        ON t1.city_id = t2.city_id
    WHERE t1.type = 1 AND t2.type = 2
) a ON a.city_id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.name from city c where exists
(select * from airport a where a.city_id=c.id and exists
(select * from airport a1 where a1.type=2 and a1.city_id=a.city_id and 
exists(select * from airport a2 where a2.type=3 and a2.city_id=a1.city_id)))
```

Check this for sample output [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c63b/4)

Answer (score -1):

You can use subquery for this.. 
Try this

```
Select Id,Name from City 
where Id in(Select distinct CityId from Airports where Type in(2,3))
```

Comment: It does not work. This returns me the cities with airports types 2,4 for example.